# Converting Java string to Date

Tags: java

I need to convert a java string in a date format to a new date format to send it to my sql-server.  Currently, my Java date is `Jul 17 2018 14:22:58`, and I need it to look like `2018-07-17 14:22:58`.  So I created this:

```
String oldTime = "Jul 17 2018 14:22:58";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS");
Date formattedDate = sdf.parse(oldTime);
```

I am getting errors that my oldTime is unparseable.  Did I do this wrong?

Comment: Your string starts with "Jul". Does that look like something that matches YYYY? Read the javadoc. That's what it's for. And no, SQL server doesn't expect a string in another format. Use the right type (a LocalDateTime, or a java.sql.Timestamp), and learn how to use prepared statements. Again, reading the documentation helps.

Comment: Incorrect format. You need to provide format for the oldTime to parse it into Date. Then you need to format Date with "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

Comment: Can we also step past the use of (effectively deprecated) `SimpeDateFormat` and move on to the new date/time APIs

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a format string that matches your date string:

```
String oldTime = "Jul 17 2018 14:22:58";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I guess my question then becomes how do I convert the date to the other format?  I assume I do that once I create the Date object?

Comment: @user3334871 "dates" don't have a prescribed format of their own - you need to use a new formatter to convert the date value back to a `String` - maybe you should start with [the Java date/time tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/index.html)